# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException from wildfly 10

Tags: java, ssl, wildfly-10, sslhandshakeexception

I'm facing an issue about TLS connection to a secure site. my application deoloyed on wildfly-10. When calling a web service overs https, it raises the exception:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:994) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:259)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector$4.getOutputStream(HttpUrlConnector.java:385)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:200)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:194)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableOutputStream.write(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:299)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1982)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:995)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:932)
at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.writeTo(ProviderBase.java:648)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.doWriteEntity(ClientRequest.java:517)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:499)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:388)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
    ... 284 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
    ... 309 more
```

I've enabled SSL logging with option -Djavax.net.debug=all. I noticed the following error:

```
[stdout] (default I/O-2) default I/O-2, fatal error: 80: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
[stdout] (default I/O-2) javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
[stdout] (default I/O-2) %% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
[stdout] (default I/O-2) default I/O-2, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
[stdout] (default I/O-2) default I/O-2, Exception sending alert: java.io.IOException: writer side was already closed.
[stdout] (default I/O-2) default I/O-2, called closeOutbound()
[stdout] (default I/O-2) default I/O-2, closeOutboundInternal()
```

Any idea about what might be the issue? Many thanks.

Comment: What exact Java version are you running ? What SSL cipher suites are allowed by the webservice you are calling ? If you can, give the full trace, we would see the handshake and guess what's wrong. Ideas are : no cipher suite in common, or missing extension (such as SNI).

Comment: Running java version 1.8.0_201. Cipher suites for tlsv1.2 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA. Cipher suites for tlsv1.1 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't show the hole ssl debug trace

Comment: You need to compare with the ones your webservice accept. You can try one by one, with an openssl command.